# Manual Tagging of Words for NLP

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, lstm, named-entity-recognition

I am a newbie in machine learning, named entity recognition and am assigned a task to manually tag my data in hundreds of paragraphs to retrain a Bidirectional LSTM model. Is there a better approach to this or i have to go through the whole content and manually tag each organization, person?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand the question, but its not as if you have to read the entire corpus. Just combine the entire corpus into a set of words, look through that set, and find anything that's an entity. You will need to be careful with how you process the text (eg can't lowercase everything b.c. then Apple -> apple and you miss that entity).  Some packages will come with some entities already recognized (like SpaCy already recognizes NATO), but your corpus will probably have some specific entities (this depends on the corpus and the software you use).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an yes or no answer to your question. I suppose you will need to use some kind of Unsupervised approach in order to prepare your supervised dataset.

[TextRank](https://github.com/summanlp/textrank) could be something very useful to you.

Otherwise I would suggest (after you do the usual pre-processing, e.g. lowercasing, punctuation removal, etc.) to apply word2vec (or any type of word vectorisation) and then some type of clustering like K-means or even better DBSCAN.

In this way you will be able to visually separate "themes/topics" in your dataset and then have a simple script to tag them.

Hope this makes sense and will be helpful.